# run internet explorer from chrome with protocol

Tags: html

I want to open webpage from internet explorer instead other browsers.
It doesn't matter user using which browser.
I was wrote a new key inside the registry to give new protocol for it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\test]
"Url Protocol"=""
@="URL:test"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\test\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\test\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\test\shell\open\command]
@="\"iexplore.exe\" \"%1\""
```

I'm writing http://google.com">test, internet explorer working but URL is like this "test://http://google.com" and I cannot open web page inside internet explorer.

How I can remove that test:// protocol from url line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than directly pointing to IE, point to something that takes the url, modifies it, and then launches it in IE.